# Python - How to find the location at the junction?

Tags: python, opencv

i have an image and i want to know how to figure out the location as i did the template. It's really hard for me a little bit, I don't have an idea for this at the moment. looking forward to help from everyone

the first image is a corner image and the second is the one where I want to find the red spot. it would be good if you guys gave me a specific example

[image: original image]

[image: second image]

Comment: sorry the title is not very clear, what i want to know is the coordinates of the red point in the second picture

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can determine the angle at each point of the contour and filter it e.g. by 45°. The result image of this code is like your example above:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la
import cv2


def get_angle(p1, p2, p3):
    v1 = np.subtract(p2, p1)
    v2 = np.subtract(p2, p3)
    cos = np.inner(v1, v2) / la.norm(v1) / la.norm(v2)
    rad = np.arccos(np.clip(cos, -1.0, 1.0))
    return np.rad2deg(rad)


img = cv2.imread('img.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:           # for each contour
    pts = [v[0] for v in c]  # get pts from contour
    n = len(pts)
    for i in range(n):       # mark points with angle < 45 deg
        if get_angle(pts[(i - 2) % n], pts[i], pts[(i + 2) % n]) < 45:
            cv2.circle(img, pts[i], 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imwrite('res.png', img)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  I will learn and save it